# show that given family is normal family

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Fix $M>0\ $and let $F\subset H(\Omega)$ be a family of functions f(z)=$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n}z^{n}$ for which $|a_{n}|\leq M$ for all n. show that $F$  is a normal family.

where $H(\Omega)$ mean set of all analytic functions on domain $\Omega$.

Comment: What's $\Omega$.? $0\in\Omega$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses  not necessary. it is general domain in complex plane